# Chrome on Windows doesnt show 'a with caron' correctly

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts

We're having some trouble displaying the latin small letter a with caron (ǎ or U+01CE)  correctly in Windows 10 - Chrome with font-family Verana. It displays the caron next to the letter 'a'. Other fonts display it correctly.

It works fine in Firefox and IE (under Windows/Linux/macOS) with Verdana.
Also Chrome in Linux/macOS displays it perfectly. The combination Windows + Chrome + Verdana seems to be the only one having difficulty.

For example, check [Graphemica a with caron](https://graphemica.com/%C7%8E) and put the font-family of the example letter on

```
font-family: Verdana
```

If you have Windows it will display the caron not above, but next to the letter 'a'.
Does anybody have an idea how we can fix this for Windows Chrome users?

Other letters with a caron, for example: č (U+010D) works fine.

Does anybody have a suggestion how we can let this 'ǎ' work in Chrome - Windows - Verdana, without changing the font?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't display correctly because U+01CE is not present in Verdana. The components (a, caron) are both present, but there is no character (nor any OpenType layout rules) that combine them into U+01CE form. When you see it "working" in other browsers, it's likely because it's substituting with a fallback font whose design is similar to Verdana (or it's at a small text size where you can't see the difference).

More about Verdana here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/verdana, have a look at the "Code pages" section. None of the listed pages contains U+01CE, so the font simply doesn't support that character. The other characters you mention are in Verdana.

To work around, you could use some simple CSS to set up a fallback for that specific unicode, for example something like this:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "fallbackfont";
  src: local('Tahoma');
  unicode-range: U+0100-01FF;
}
```

```html
<p style='font-family: fallbackfont, Verdana; font-size:72px'>a &#x01CE;</p>
```

**NOTE**: I chose local 'Tahoma' for a fallback here because its design is more similar to Verdana than others. And it is selected for use for the entire Unicode range of U+0100-01FF. But you could (probably *should*) use a webfont or other local/"web-safe" font of your choosing. Also, you could set the `unicode-range` for just the one character if you're sure that's the only one not displaying correctly for your text.

Comment: (I know I shouldn't comment with just a 'thank you'. But I'm so intrigued by your answer..) Thank you very much for such a comprehensive answer, I've learned a lot from this!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help! Fonts can be a bit of a "dark art" :-)